# How to fill up a range with data from a smaller range in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

[The first image is my data which is in the range A1:A10 on Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkUvO.png)

[The second image is the desired result in Sheet2 that I want to get after I copy/paste my data from Sheet1. How do I copy/paste my data on Sheet1 repeatedly to fill the range A1:A200 on Sheet2. Can you help me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKCbz.png)

Answer (score 2):

## Hard Coded

### When The Source Range Fits Right Into the Target Range

This solution uses the code names of the worksheets, so you can rename the worksheets as you wish and the code will still work. In VBE in the properties window (F4) the code names are referred to as '(Name)', while the worksheet names, the ones you see in the Excel tabs, are referred to as 'Name'.

```
Sub Copy10To200()
    Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1:A200")
' Instead of:
'  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Copy _
      Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B200")
End Sub
```

### A Little More Advanced Version

What happens if the source range **doesn't fit** right into the target range is described in the **remarks** section at the **end** of the following code.

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:  Uses a one-column range of values on a worksheet to fill up
'           a larger one-column range on a second worksheet.
'*******************************************************************************
Sub SmallColumnToColumn()

  ' Declare variables.
  Const cStrSource As String = "A1:A10"
  Const cStrTarget As String = "B1:B200"
  Dim objRngSource As Range
  Dim objRngTarget As Range
  Dim lngRowsSource As Long
  Dim lngRowsTarget As Long
  Dim lngINT As Long
  Dim lngMOD As Long

  Const blnActiveWorkbook As Boolean = False

    '***************************************************************************
    ' Additional Functionality:
    '   When FALSE is assigned to the previous boolean (blnActiveWorkbook),
    '   the initial functionality is triggered i.e. it only works within
    '   the workbook where it resides (ThisWorkbook) which is noticable in the
    '   following ELSE statement where also the codenames should be changed,
    '   if necessary.
    '   On the other hand, when TRUE is assigned, the initial functionality
    '   is expanded to any ActiveWorkbook which is noticable in the following
    '   WITH statement. The values (strings) of the codenames can now be changed
    '   in the following two CONSTANT STRING variables if necessary.
    '***************************************************************************

  ' Create references to the ranges.
  If blnActiveWorkbook Then
    ' Additional Functionality
    Const cStrCodeNameSource As String = "Sheet1" ' CodeName (Sheet1)
    Const cStrCodeNameTarget As String = "Sheet2" ' CodeName (Sheet2)
    With ActiveWorkbook
      On Error GoTo WorksheetSourceHandler
      Set objRngSource = .Worksheets(CStr(.VBProject.VBComponents _
          (cStrCodeNameSource).Properties(7))).Range(cStrSource) 'CodeName
      On Error GoTo WorksheetTargetHandler
      Set objRngTarget = .Worksheets(CStr(.VBProject.VBComponents _
          (cStrCodeNameTarget).Properties(7))).Range(cStrTarget) 'CodeName
    End With
   Else
    ' Initial Functionality
    Set objRngSource = Sheet1.Range(cStrSource) 'CodeName Sheet1
    Set objRngTarget = Sheet2.Range(cStrTarget) 'CodeName Sheet2
    ' No error handling needed, because if one of the worksheets doesn't exist,
    ' the following error occurs: "Compile error: Variable not defined"
  End If

  ' Assign the number of rows in the ranges to variables.
  lngRowsSource = objRngSource.Rows.Count
  lngRowsTarget = objRngTarget.Rows.Count

  ' Check if the first range has more rows then the second one.
  ' This ensures that lngINT (later in the code) is greater than 0.
  If lngRowsSource > lngRowsTarget Then GoTo RowsHandler

  ' DEL the target column (ClearContents).
'  objRngTarget.EntireColumn.ClearContents
'  Range(objRngTarget.Resize(Rows.Count, 1).Address).ClearContents 'HaHaHa...

  ' Check if accidentally a multiple-columns range was specified. If so, resize
  ' the range to first-column-only.
  Set objRngSource = objRngSource.Resize(lngRowsSource, 1)
  Set objRngTarget = objRngTarget.Resize(lngRowsTarget, 1)

  ' Calculate INT and MOD
  lngINT = Int(lngRowsTarget / lngRowsSource)
  lngMOD = lngRowsTarget Mod lngRowsSource

  ' Copy/paste range INT times.
  objRngSource.Copy Destination:=objRngTarget.Resize(lngINT * lngRowsSource, 1)

  ' Additionally copy/paste the first MOD number of rows.
  If lngMOD > 0 Then
    objRngSource.Resize(lngMOD, 1).Copy Destination:= _
        objRngTarget.Offset(lngINT * lngRowsSource, 0).Resize(lngMOD, 1)
  End If

ProcedureExit:

  ' Release object variables.
  Set objRngSource = Nothing
  Set objRngTarget = Nothing

Exit Sub

' Handle errors.

RowsHandler:
  MsgBox "The source range (" & lngRowsSource & ") has to have fewer rows" _
      & " than the target range (" & lngRowsTarget & ")."
  GoTo ProcedureExit

WorksheetSourceHandler:
  Select Case Err.Number
    Case 9
      MsgBox "There is no sheet with the CodeName '" & cStrCodeNameSource _
          & "' to read from. Change the value in " _
          & "'Const cStrCodeNameSource As String ='"
    Case 1004
      MsgBox "The range '" & cStrSource & "' is not a valid range." _
          & " Change the value in " _
          & "'Const cStrSource As String = '"
    Case Else
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occured. Error '" & Err.Number & "'"
  End Select
  GoTo ProcedureExit

WorksheetTargetHandler:
  Select Case Err.Number
    Case 9
      MsgBox "There is no sheet with the CodeName '" & cStrCodeNameTarget _
          & "' to write to. Change the value in " _
          & "'Const cStrCodeNameTarget As String ='"
    Case 1004
      MsgBox "The range '" & cStrTarget & "' is not a valid range." _
          & " Change the value in " _
          & "'Const cStrTarget As String = '"
    Case Else
      MsgBox "An unexpected error has occured. Error '" & Err.Number & "'"
  End Select
  GoTo ProcedureExit

End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
' Remarks:
'   The Copy Method
'     When using Destination with the Copy Method and the target range is bigger
'     than the source range, the method atempts to fill the target range with
'     the source range and it succeeds, if the source range fits EXACTLY ANY
'     number of times into the target range. If it doesn't fit it pastes the
'     source range ONLY ONCE, into the BEGINNING of the target range.
'     In this code this issue is a little simplified due to the fact that it is
'     using only one-colum ranges. The issue is resolved by using the INT
'     function to calculate the amount of times the source range fits into
'     the target range and by pasting it as many times, and additionally by
'     using the MOD function to calculate the remainder of rows (if any) which
'     is then used to copy the first rows of the source range to fill up the
'     rest of the target range.
'*******************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your code really helped me, and I really appreciate you, for your step by step code description

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for the reply and the reward. Happy coding.

Comment: if I want to copy in a different column for example column b. what should I edit

Comment: At the beginning of the code there are cStrSource and cStrTarget for you to edit as you please. So if you want to COPY FROM a different range just change the cStrSource to e.g. "B22:B31". Or if you want to PASTE INTO a different range just change the cStrTarget to e.g. "F100:F1000". That is why using constants is important. It makes it easy to change the values, because they are all at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Macro1()

    For a = 1 To 200 Step 10
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & a)
    Next

End Sub
```